# jQuery console loads twice in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jquery

I am having issues with this jQuery code.  I don't understand why my function runs twice. 'dosomething' and data shows up twice in the console and i'm not sure why.  Please help.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    loadReportData();
})

function loadReportData(){
  $.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('individual')/items",
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "Accept":"application/json;odata=verbose"   
    },
    success:dosomething,
    error:dosomethingelse
  })    

}

function dosomething(data){
 console.log("dosomething");
 console.log(data);

}
```

[image]

console
[image]

Comment: It works well in my environment.Could you share a screenshot about the issue?

Comment: Did you call loadReportData twice in the page?

Comment: No I did not.  I added images to the question

Comment: You were right @Amos_MSFT!!  There was a hidden webpart on the page with the same code.  Thanks!